# difficulty on method parameters for squaring numbers

Tags: java

This is what my assignment calls for:

> Create a method that declares four int parameters, squares each, and
> places the results in a float array. The method should return the
> float array result. Name the method square.

This is the closest that I have gotten to getting the assignment right.

```
public class Square {
    
    public static  double [] main(String[] args) {
    (int a, int b, int c, int d);
    double [] result = {a*a, b*b,c*c,d*d};
    return result;      
    
        System.out.println(result);         
        
    }    
}
```

With the code that I have used, it has displayed one error. If someone can show me where I went wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. (1) Code format is not correct. (2) You said it displays one error however we don't know what that error is. Can you please provide that?

Comment: There is a parameter set right after your opening braces to your main method. Syntax is very off. Consider going through a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The return statement`return result;` should be the last statement in your function but it is not.

`System.out.println(result)` is the last one right now. Depending on your compiler or environment this is either marked as an error or ignored since its unreachable code.

Also the brackets `(int a, int b, int c, int d);` may lead to an error but since you dont give us the error message we can only provide suggestions.

Based on @Omar Abdel Bari feedback the return type double[] must be void since its the main entry method.

Comment: I think yall are missing the main problem here is in the first 2 lines of code.

Comment: Good catch i missed the double return type!